# Mailchimp: UNSUB does not return the URL

Tags: mailchimp

*|UNSUB|* is not generating the automatic subscription URL. Instead of that, it return null in href attr. I have sent an email using send Test option. Please advice me.

Following tags are also not working.

*|ARCHIVE|*
*|UPDATE_PROFILE|*
*|FORWARD|*

EDIT:

It is working in campaign mode. It won't work in testing mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some tests in mailchimp. After the long time, I found. It is working in campaign mode. It won't work in testing mode

Answer (score 0):

if you connect the campaign to an audience then the unsubscribe link arrives correct even in the test phase

[image]